# How to get ALL elements of simplexml object

Tags: php, simplexml

OK, I'm totally stumped here. I've found similar questions, but the answers don't seem to work for my specific problem. I've been working on this on and off for days.

I have this here simplexml object (it's actually much, much, MUCH longer than this, but I'm cutting out all the extraneous stuff so you'll actually look at it):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [SubjectClassification] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Authority] => Category Code
                            [Value] => s
                            [Id] => s
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Authority] => Subject
                            [Value] => Sports
                            [Id] => 54df6c687df7100483dedf092526b43e
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Authority] => Subject
                            [Value] => Professional baseball
                            [Id] => 20dd2c287e4e100488e5d0913b2d075c
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I got this block of code by doing a print_r on a variable containing the following:

```
$subjects->SubjectClassification->children();
```

Now, I want to get at all the elements of the subjectClassification array. ALL of them! But when I do this:

```
$subjects->SubjectClassification;
```

Or this:

```
$subjects->SubjectClassification->children();
```

OR if I try to get all the array elements via a loop, all I get is this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Authority] => Category Code
            [Value] => s
            [Id] => s
        )

)
```

Why? How can I get everything?

Comment: You should show the code you're using to get those results. When you say you used a loop, did you echo within the loop? Outside of it? etc...

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that the first block of code is a variable called `$subjects`. When I do this:

    `$subjects = $subjects->SubjectClassification;
    print_r($subjects);`

I get the second block of code.

Comment: I'm slightly confused - your question says the first output is from `$subjects->SubjectClassification->children()`, but your comment that it's from `$subjects`. And reassigning back to the same variable name is just going to make things more confusing. A sample of the XML and the PHP code you're running would help here.

Comment: You should always add some example XML and then say by example what you expect to get as well.

Comment: Hey, have you already had your own answer?

Answer (score 2):

For all *descendants* (that are children, grand-children, grand-grand-children, grand-grand-... (you get the idea)) of `<subjectClassification>`s (*"all the elements [...] ALL of them!"* as you named it), you can make use of Xpath which supports such more advanced queries (at least I assume that is what you're looking for, your question does not give any detailed discription nor example what you mean by *"all"* specifically).

As for SimpleXML you can query elements (and attributes) only with Xpath, but as you need elements only, this is no show stopper:

```
$allOfThem = $subjects->xpath('./SubjectClassification//*');
```

The key point here is the Xpath expression:

```
./SubjectClassification//*
```

Per the dot `.` at the beginning it is relative to the context-node, which is `$subjects` in your case. Then looking for all elements that are descending to the direct child-element named *`SubjectClassification`*. This works per `//` (unspecified depth) and `*` (any element, star acts as a wildcard).

So hopefully this answers your question months after. I just stumbled over it by cleaning up some XML questions and perhaps this is useful for future reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to do this. Its the easiest way and most efficient I find and cuts down the need for lots of for loops and such to resolve items. To get all the nodes you want you can use:

if your xml is like this:

```
<Subjects>
<SubjectClassification>
</SubjectClassification>
<SubjectClassification>
</SubjectClassification>
<SubjectClassification>
</SubjectClassification>
</Subjects>
```

Then to get all subject classifications in an array you can do the following:

```
$subject_classifications = $xml->xpath("//SubjectClassification");
```

The xml variable refers to your main simplexml object i.e. the file you loaded using simplexml.

Then you can just iterate through the array using a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($subject_classifications as $subject_classification){
echo (string) $subject_classification->Authority;
echo (string) $subject_classification->Value;
echo (string) $subject_classification->Id;
}
```

Your structure may vary but you get the idea anyway. You can see a good article from IBM here ["Using Xpath With PHP"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xpathphp/):

Comment: jiraiya, thanks for that. I may give that a go, but what you can't see in my question is that the XML structure is very, very complex.

Comment: Ah I see, well I would still give xpath a try if its within the scope of the project and if you have the time. I just finished a project myself with lots of complex xml in it and only for xpath it would have been hell to iterate through. Xpath allows you to instantly retrieve a node or all sub nodes. Then you can just do a print_r or var_dump, examine the structure and it should be ok to write your loop then as you would have a clear blue print to do it from.

Comment: The downside to using XPath is that you lose the context of your matches - you will get a list of `SubjectClassification` nodes, but have no simple way of knowing which `Subject` they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the extent to which SimpleXML overloads PHP syntax, relying on `print_r` to figure out what's in a SimpleXML object, or what you can do with it, is not always helpful. (I've written [a couple of debugging functions](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) intended to be more comprehensive.) Ultimately, the reference should be to the XML structure itself, and knowledge of how SimpleXML works.

In this case, it looks from the output you provide that what you have is a list of elements all called `SubjectClassification`, and all siblings to each other. So you don't want to call `$subjects->SubjectClassification->children()`, because those nodes have no children.

Without a better idea of the underlying XML structure, it's hard to say more, so I'll save this incomplete answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this second answer in case whats actually throwing you is retrieving the attributes array as opposed to the nodes. This is how you could print out the attributes for each SubjectClassification in your main $xml object.

```
foreach($xml->SubjectClassification->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " : " . $value "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `count` returns the proper number of elements, and you can then use a standard `for` loop to iterate over them:

```
$n = count($subjects->SubjectClassification);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    var_dump($subjects->SubjectClassification[$i]);
}
```

I'm not sure why the `foreach` loop doesn't work, nor why dumping `$subjects->SubjectClassification` directly only shows the first node, but for any who stumble across this ancient question as I have, the above is one way to find more information without resorting to external libraries.